# handling the spaces of file paths in batch file that read out from a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am reading the path of files over a file `paths.lst` in a for loop and looking for a 'Value' parameter to be replaced in particular `xml` files.

The content of the `paths.lst` file is as follows:

```
C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir1}\test.xml
C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir2}\test.xml
C:\Users\ect\docdoc\testdir\conf\{testdir3}\test.xml
```

```bash
@echo off

for /f %%i in (paths.lst) do call :$change %%i
REM exit

:$change
set filePath='%1'
echo Value changed for:'%filePath%'
set fold='Value=\"0\"'
set fnew='Value=\"1\"'
powershell -Command "(gc %filePath%) -replace %fold%, %fnew% | Out-File %filePath% -encoding utf8"
```

The first and second paths can not be read out, due to empty spaces, but the script works for the third path `C:\Users\ect\docdoc\testdir\conf\{testdir3}\test.xml`

Comment: What is the value of `%filePath%`? and where is it defined? Also are you specifically telling us that you have Windows directory names with trailing spaces?

Comment: Sorry, it is corrected now. `The set file='%1'` should be actually `set filePath='%1'`

Comment: and my other question...

Comment: No trailing spaces in the directory names.

Comment: `for /f "delims="...`, `...call :$change "%%i"`, remove `set filePath='%1'` and
`echo Value changed for:'%filePath%'` then use `powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(gc '%~1') -replace %fold%, %fnew% | Out-File '%~1' -encoding utf8` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

- replace `for /f %%i` with `for /f "delims=" %%i` so as to read each whole line (otherwise the default delimiters are tab and space)
- replace `call :$change %%i` with `call :$change "%%i"` so as to pass quoted filenames to your subroutine
- within the subroutine you might need to replace `%1` with `"%~1"`. With the tilde you strip any double quotes if they existed, and then you add new ones.

Comment: Still the same error: `Value changed for:'"C:\Users\ect\doc"'
gc : Access to the path "C:\Users\ect\doc" was denied.
In Line:1 Character:2
+ (gc C:\Users\ect\doc) -replace 'Value="0"', ' ...`

Comment: @mystic.06 sorry, I forgot something. I amended my answer.

Comment: It is maybe out of topic but I have now another issue. If the file `paths.lst` contains 10 paths only 9 of them are processed in the for loop. So always one paths less. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: That's weird. I do not really know what the reason is for that, and I cannot even guess what the reason **could be** for that. One thing which should not really make any difference, but might be worth trying, is to ensure that the file ends with an end-of-line sequence.

Answer (score 1):

[Mike Nakis' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76003917/45375) covers the `cmd.exe` side of things well.

Let me address the *PowerShell* side of things:

- `{` and `}` are *metacharacters* in PowerShell, so a file path such as `C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir1}\test.xml` is *not* taken literally *if used unquoted* as a command argument in PowerShell code.

  - Therefore, `gc %filePath%` will *fail* with such paths.
- PowerShell's initial command-line parsing *removes* the `\` from `\"` sequences, so that `'Value=\"0\"'` is seen as verbatim `'Value="0"'` when the PowerShell code executes.

  - It just so happens that in the context of a *regex* (as used by `-replace`) that is specified via a PowerShell `'...'` string literal, these two values are equivalent (`"` chars. don't require escaping in regexes, though escaping them does no harm), but it is something to be aware of.
- A simple way to avoid quoting and escaping headaches is to rely on the fact that `cmd.exe`'s variables (created with `set`) are invariably also *environment* variables, which PowerShell therefore inherits; e.g., the value of `fold` (`%fold%`) can be accessed via `$env:fold` in the PowerShell code.  This indirect way of referencing the value provides *robust* access to its verbatim value.
- You can then focus on setting the variable values *without* needing to use `'...'` quoting for the benefit of PowerShell.

  - The most robust way to set arbitrary values in a `cmd.exe` `SET` statement is to enclose the name, `=`, and value in `"..."` *overall*; e.g., to make `fold` contain *verbatim* `Value=\"0\"`, use `set "fold=Value=\"0\""`
  - As noted, the `~` in `%~1` removes any enclosing `"` that are part of the value, so that `set "filePath=%~1"` robustly stores the *unquoted* path in `filePath`.

To put it all together:

```bash
@echo off & setlocal

:: Note the "delims=" and the %%i enclosed in "..."
for /f "delims=" %%i in (paths.lst) do call :$change "%%i"
goto :EOF

:$change
  :: Note the "..." around the name, "=", and the value *overall*.
  :: No need for '...' quoting.
  set "filePath=%~1"
  set "fold=Value=\"0\""
  set "fnew=Value=\"1\""
  :: Note the $env: references to the variables defined above.
  powershell -Command "(gc $env:filePath) -replace $env:fold, $env:fnew | Out-File $env:filePath -encoding utf8"
  echo Value changed for: "%filePath%"
goto :EOF
```